# NodeJS emit to specific room [socket.io]

Tags: node.js, socket.io

It seems that I'm not the only one struggling with this problem.

However I am trying to write a simple chat application.  When a user joins a room, the roomID is saved in socket.room.id.  It is just a number.

When they join / change rooms, I have the following code:

```
// Notify the rooms
if(previousRoomID) io.to(previousRoomID).emit("activity-notification","<b>"+socket.me.name+"</b> has left the room " + previousRoomID);

io.to(socket.room.id).emit("activity-notification","<b>"+socket.me.name+"</b> has joined the room " + socket.room.id);
```

Now, Let's say that `previousRoomID = 1`, and `socket.room.id = 30`.

It sends the message, but they both seem to go to *all* users.  If I am in roomID 1, and a user leaves the room, I get the following messages:

```
user has left the room 1
user has joined the room 30
```

I shouldnt be able to see the second message, because in the code above I am sending it to `io.to(socket.room.id).emit()`, yet even when I am in room 1 I am getting this message.

Strangely enough also, It seems to be using the broadcast functionality as well, even though I am not calling it; as in - it sends it to all users except the one who fired the event.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have this figured out.  The problem was I was calling

`socket.join(roomID)`

But I wasn't leaving a room first.  So it turns out that a socket can join multiple rooms, which would explain why I was seeing both the messages.

```
if(previousRoomID) socket.leave(previousRoomID);
socket.join(roomID)
if(previousRoomID) io.to(previousRoomID).emit("activity-notification","<b>"+socket.me.name+"</b> has left the room");
io.to(socket.room.id).emit("activity-notification","<b>"+socket.me.name+"</b> has joined the room");
```

I dont understand the broadcast functionality though, in theory the messages should be going to everyone but for some reason the socket that calls the `io.to.emit` line doesnt get the `activity-notification`.